# C# application autostart on Windows start

Tags: c#, autostart

I've created an application who have an option for create a shortcut on Start Menu for autostart on windows start.
All works but I need to do something in order to let the software programmatically understand if software is started by windows (automatically) or by the user.

Now I verify if shortcut exists but I want understand if exists some parameter to use for understand if  Windows run program or not.

Comment: You could possibly pass in a command line argument. No guarantee though that users can't figure out and do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During your setup, have the program start with an argument like

`myApp.exe autoStart`

This way if your app is started via startup or w/e it will have that command line argument, which you can check like

```
bool AutoStartMode = false; 

//--somewhere near startup

var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if (args != null && args.Any(arg => arg == "autoStart"))
{
   AutoStartMode = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Run key in the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx) for your auto start.  You will create a sub key for your app under the run key.  The value of your key will be the path to your application and any command line parameters you wish to use.  One of the parameters could indicate that the application is being started automatically.  Kyle provided an example of how you could check for a specific command line parameter.

Comment: though your option sounds feasible I hate working with the registry because of permissions set on various PCs/group policies differently, @Kyle Golble's approach is elegant and there are no permissions to check for. That's just my opinion....